# Permanent Redirect 308 Error in JMeter Put Request

Tags: jmeter, request, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am facing 308 Error while doing JMeter PUT Request
But same PUT request working fine in Post man

[image: JMeter settings]
[image: JMeter settings]
Above Is the screenshots of my settings.
Pls suggest to solve this issue

Comment: Did you try `Follow redirects`?

Comment: Yes. It goes to Get Request instead of PUT

Comment: After Get it went to PUT but same error only

Answer (score 0):

If your request works fine in Postman and doesn't work in JMeter the easiest way to get it up and running is just recording the request from Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

1. [Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

   [image]
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman.
5. JMeter will capture the request and create the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and you should be able to replay the request.

Comment: after setting the proxy...not able to connect host